# DirectoryWalker filter folder having xml file in them

Tags: java, apache, file, file-io, directory

I am using the DirectoryWalker and I want to create a filter that will list all the directories that contain xml files. I do not want to list the file themselves but only their direct parent? If a directory only directories I do not want to list it. Do you believe it to be feasible?

I have been looking at the sample at http://people.apache.org/~jochen/commons-io/site/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html#filter but I did not find one that seemed to do what I want.

```
public class ExtractedDirectoryWalker extends DirectoryWalker {

public ExtractedDirectoryWalker() {
    super();
}

public ArrayList<File> getDirectories(File startDirectory) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    walk(startDirectory, dirs);
    return dirs;
}

@Override
protected boolean handleDirectory(File directory, int depth,
    Collection results) {
    results.add(directory);
    return true;
}
```

}

From another class:

```
List<File> directories = new ExtractedDirectoryWalker()
                    .getDirectories(outputFolder.toFile());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the code, but I think this should work:

```
private static final FileFilter filter = new XMLChildFileFilter();

public ExtractedDirectoryWalker() {
    super(filter, -1);
}
private static class XMLChildFileFilter implements FileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if(file == null || !file.isDirectory() || !file.canRead()) {
            return false;
        }
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for(File f : files) {
            if(f.isFile()) {
                if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.getName()).equals("xml"))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```